# Linking each text word or words divided by comma into an existing URL?

Tags: php, wordpress, function, hyperlink, shortcode

I am trying to auto add each word or words divided by comma into an existing url.

I have url lets say `http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=HERE IS THAT TEXT`.

I have this function:

```
function movie_cast( $atts, $content = null ) {
    return '<div class="movie_cast">Cast: '.$content.'</div>';
}

add_shortcode( 'movie_cast', 'movie_cast' );
```

I am using it: `[movie_cast]Actor 1, Actor 2[/movie_cast]`

Output from this is just text: `Actor 1, Actor 2`

How can I get otput it like this: `<a href="http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Actor 1">Actor 1</a>, <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Actor 2">Actor 2</a>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you mean? This code would be called like `movie_cast("Actor 1, Actor 2")` or `[movie_cast]Actor 1, Actor 2[/movie_cast]` and would return the output you asked for.

Explode splits the string on the comma's, the condition places a comma after each link except for the last and the rest is just string concatenation.

```
function movie_cast( $atts ) {
    $url = "http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=";
    $str = "";
    foreach (explode(", ",$atts) as $value)
    {
        if ($str != "") $str .= ", ";
        $str .= "<a href=\"" . $url . $value . "\">" . $value . "</a>";
    }

    return $str;
}
```